# Is there a way to target multiple conditions with a single switch match in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell

In an example script, I want to execute one block of code if my variable matches 1, another one if it matches 2, 3, 5, or 8, and a different block for 4, 6, or 7.

I'd like to do something like this:

```
switch($x)
{
    1 {'Condition 1'}
    2 -or 3 -or -5 -or 8 {'Condition 2'}
    4 -or 6 -or 7 {'Condition 3'}
}
```

But this doesn't work. Is there a way to do this sort of work with switch, without having to spell out all 8 options individually, or are multiple if statements the only way to go?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Another option, if you want to treat the values as numbers instead of strings:

```
switch ($x)
{
    1                {'Condition 1'}
    {$_ -in 2,3,5,8} {'Condition 2'}
    {$_ -in 4,6,7}   {'Condition 3'}
}
```

Comment: Another (much more verbose) option for Condition 2: `{$_ -eq 2 -or $_ -eq 3 -or $_ -eq 5 -or $_ -eq 8}`. The key here was recognizing that the object checked by `switch` can be referenced with `$_` and that script blocks can be used as conditions. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You can use the -Regex option and do something like this:

```
switch -Regex ($x)
{
  '1'       {'Condition 1'}
  '[2358]'  {'Condition 2'}
  '[467]'   {'Condition 3'}
}
```